# How to run solver function macro with "ByChange:" multiple variables that are indirectly referenced and are not an array?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, solver

I am aiming to use the solver function within VBA with a by change variable that is indirectly referenced Range:("J" & RowNumber1), which is a value that I am using an for loop and if then statement to iteratively find. VBA is fine with declaring this variable solely in ByChange: but cannot properly solve with declared individual separate cells that are indirectly referenced and instead views them as an array rather than two individual cells as shown below. Is there a way to have the solver function within VBA be properly used given this circumstance? Thanks

```
For J = 20 To 25
    If PC.Cells(J, 8).Value2 = EB Then
    RowNumber1 = J
    VK = PC.Cells(RowNumber1, 10).Value2



        With PC

        SolverReset


        SolverOK setCell:=Range("AF16"), _
        maxMinVal:=3, _
        ValueOf:=DPen, _
        **ByChange:=Range("J" & RowNumber1, "G16")**, _
        Engine:=1, _
        EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"

        SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("AG16"), _
        Relation:=2, _
        FormulaText:=91.8



        SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ByChange:=Range("J" & RowNumber1 & ",G16"), Engine:=1, _
```